# netcore 2.0 not logging trace and debug when logging created in DI container

Tags: logging, .net-core-2.0

I have a console app that will use DI to supply configuration (Options Pattern), logging and other service references to services within the app.

I have a problem in that logging is working for Info/Warning/Error/Critical but **Debug** and **Trace** are not showing up.  I have set the console level to Trace.  If I just create a logger factory, all logs are shown.

It sounds like it is using defaults.  For loggers created in the DI service collection, is there another way to configure the log level?

I have tried adding a dispose on the service collection as referred to in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187323/netcore-not-logging-to-console) post, Edit 2 link and no luck.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console;
using System;

namespace DownloadClientData.App
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            //***if I use this way to create the logger in the DI container, debug and trace messages are not displayed
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddLogging();

            //tried this alternative too - no change...
            //serviceCollection.AddLogging(LoggingBuilder => LoggingBuilder.AddFilter<ConsoleLoggerProvider>("All Categories", LogLevel.Trace));
            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

            //***If I comment out the above lines and uncomment the below line, all 6 logs are displayed.

            //var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
            loggerFactory
                .AddConsole(LogLevel.Trace)
                .AddDebug(LogLevel.Trace);

            var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(typeof(Program));
            logger.LogInformation("Information");
            logger.LogTrace("Trace");
            logger.LogDebug("Debug");
            logger.LogWarning("Warning");
            logger.LogCritical("Critical");
            logger.LogError("Error");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;

            }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The defaults for the minimum log level are different when using the `AddLogging()` extension method on `ServiceCollection`. You can set it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddLogging(builder => {
            builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            builder.AddConsole();
            builder.AddDebug();
        });

    var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(typeof(Program));
    logger.LogInformation("Information");
    logger.LogTrace("Trace");
    logger.LogDebug("Debug");
    logger.LogWarning("Warning");
    logger.LogCritical("Critical");
    logger.LogError("Error");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I also had to remove any specific logger factory setup on the retrieved loggerFactory and move this to the logging builder.  It is implied by your code but wanted to point that out to other readers.  Otherwise weird stuff happens...  Thanks again.  M.,