# ILogger that outputs into dotnet test

Tags: unit-testing, logging, .net-core

When I do

```
LoggerFactory
  .Create(builder => builder.AddTraceSource(nameof(TestName)).AddConsole())
  .CreateLogger(nameof(TestName))
  .LogError("oh no");
```

I kind of expect that "oh no" will be visible in `dotnet test --verbosity detailed` output. But it is not. How to obtain ILogger so that its output is visible in test run output?

I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 3.0.0-preview3.19153.1 and .NET Core SDK 2.1.500.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because console logging is performed in background thread. So to "fix" this try to either [dispose services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187323/netcore-not-logging-to-console) :

```
((IDisposable) services)?.Dispose();
```

or at least [give it some time](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/631) to handle - sleep for a second:

```
LoggerFactory
  .Create(builder => builder.AddTraceSource(nameof(TestName)).AddConsole())
  .CreateLogger(nameof(TestName))
  .LogError("oh no");

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```